# play framework java rest api example

Tags: java, rest, playframework

I'm starting in the play framework with Java and downloaded the project from the official website: https://github.com/playframework/play-java-rest-api-example/tree/2.5.x

I joined the eclipse as it says at: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/IDE

And run the command: sbt run
It worked. However, if I send a post to the given address, I get the message "Unauthorized".

Does anyone know if I have to do anything else?

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One thing I discovered:
1) I leave the postman selected "POST" and with the Json of the body already filled;
2) reboot the machine
3) when connecting, I run sbt run
4) I can do POST normally
5) change to GET
6) I retrieve all the data
7) change back to POST
8) from there, I get the 403 Forbidden error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is workin for me .

@Singleton
public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

```
private final Environment env;
private final EssentialFilter exampleFilter;

@Inject
public Filters(Environment env, ExampleFilter exampleFilter) {
    this.env = env;
    this.exampleFilter = exampleFilter;
}

@Override
public EssentialFilter[] filters() {

  if (env.mode().equals(Mode.DEV)) {
      return new EssentialFilter[] { exampleFilter };
  } else {
     return new EssentialFilter[] {};
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found out. I have not yet studied Filters, but I left it that way and it worked:[image]

Answer (score 0):

another way is to configure it in the application.conf file, just add the lines

```
play.filters.disabled +="play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"
```